# SSRS2016 - Web portal error

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2016

Yesterday I upgraded Sql server 2014 to Sql server 2016 RTM. 
When i go to reporting services web portal i get error popup

```
"Could not load folder contents
Something went wrong. Please try again later. "
```

I tried:

- Repair instalation
- Restore database
- Restart reporting service
- Restart PC
- Restore encryption key

but nothing helped. 
Do anyone know what could happen ?

[image: SSRS 2016 Error]

Thanks

**EDIT:**  When i use `http://<server>/reportserver` i see all my reports and they work fine.

Comment: Did you figure it out finally?

Comment: Yes helped to install cumulative update pack 1 ... these days is available at least cumulative update pack 2 too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cumulative update 1  (CU1) solved issue.. Today is available also (CU4)

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems like you have a path with an invalid character. I would try running the following query against the ReportServer database:

```
SELECT c.[Path] FROM [ReportServer]..[Catalog] c
ORDER BY c.[Path]
```

From there, you should be able to review each path and confirm whether you have something with an illegal character.

Comment: i found 2 paths: 
on ID1: is path empty string
on id2: /{Guid-Number}
do you thing i can remove them ?

Comment: @PeterM. Are you worried about losing what's there already? You should be able to remove them (at least, it worked on my test server)... Just delete the row from the catalog table, but be sure you backup the DB first.

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/2773254/ssrs-2016-bug Found this online as well.

Comment: No No i am not worried to delete but these 2 keys because i have backup. Anyway I think they are system keys and is not possible to delete them because other rows reference them are as parents so i think they are service keys.
About your second with connect link solution working. Please you can post as answer